# Older Questions with Misleading Titles

Tags: discussion, duplicates

After posting my question about [cut time](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14431/the-importance-of-cut-time) someone pointed out the question may have already been answered in [another question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/568/is-there-any-real-world-difference-between-time-signatures-such-as-4-4-and-8-8). By the title alone, it did not seem like it was directly related to cut time (2/2), but the answer did address cut time.

I thought this was a one off issue and I just had to be more careful asking questions, but I have noticed a few other instances of this. For example, I wanted to ask the question "Can a bass run through a guitar amp damage a guitar amp?" and found [Using an electric bass guitar with a guitar amp / hi-fi system](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3474/using-an-electric-bass-guitar-with-a-guitar-amp-hi-fi-system) which kind of addresses the question, but it took a bit of searching to find it and just from reading the title I wouldn't have know it answered my question. Also today I though of asking "Knowing when to replace strings on a guitar or bass." and found [How often should I replace the strings on my guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/how-often-should-i-replace-the-strings-on-my-guitar) which the answer for this kind of answers the question I have along with the question in the title.

My though is we need to people to able to search for the answer to their question without have to search though questions that may not be relevant and titles should directly relate to the content of the questions/anwsers. I was thinking we could edit the older question's titles to better reflect what is being ask/answered or if different questions are answered in the answerer that do not reflect the question we would let those questions be asked while linking to the older questions. Or is this just a non issue that we shouldn't worry about.

Edit:
Found a good example of a [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10868/raised-leading-tones-in-phrygian-mode-counterpoint) spawned from another question. Should this method be followed, or should something else be done?

Comment: I'm not an experienced-enough user to say whether we'll come up with a special solution, but you're always free to edit questions yourself.

Comment: @Kevin I would just like to know how everyone feels about it. I could do this, but someone else may have a better solution.

Comment: Have you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)? Not all duplication is bad and it can sometimes even be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Often, a major source of this issue is when users (often beginners) ask questions but don't know the answer will discuss a topic, and therefore the question often never addresses the concept. For example, suppose I asked "Why does D7 work in C major even though F♯ is not in the key signature?". Answers might discuss secondary dominants and maybe other topics, but as the question asker, I'd never know to put Secondary Dominants in the title, or even in the tags.